# In java enviroment, how associate a process to run on a specific monitor?

Tags: java

I have two monitor and two process. I need to associate a process to a specific monitor. 
But i have difficult to find command to execute this operation:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder1 = new ProcessBuilder("HERE PATH OF MY FILE","COMMAND TO RUN ON A DISPLAY");

Process p1= processBuilder1.start();
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to define where 'command' is being run - this may be operating system specific information.  For example, you may try command = "terminal -e command" on a Linux environment.  Re: https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the

Comment: I try to use the ProcessBuider class to insert a command as you explain, but the problem is that I'm not able to find a specific command for this operation. You can see the code updated. Thanks